# Running two api's simultaneously using GCD in ios

Tags: iphone, ios6, grand-central-dispatch, speech-to-text

I am working on radio application where i need to convert speech to text. For that i am using third party api's. For geting better results i want to run two api's at the same time and compare the output. this should happen when user clicks on record button.

I know we can do this using GCD but not getting exact idea of how we can achieve this.

Need suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Th short answer is that you create two GCD queues, one for each Speech-to-Text task. Within each block, you call the two different APIs with the same input data.  Then you either wait for the result, or get the block to invoke a callback status method when completed.

Note that you will need to ensure that the speech engines can safely run on background threads.

This is fairly straightforward if you want to record the audio first, then submit the data to two different engines for processing.  But it sounds like you might want to start processing the audio as soon as the user clicks Record? In that case, it very much depends on the APIs as to how you feed them data in real time. You might want to just run them on separate threads explicitly and feed them data as it comes in.